# Alert "interrupts" jquery animation

Tags: jquery, animation, alert, freeze

If I'm running some jQuery animation and I'll call an alert, the animation will freeze and will continue when I close the alert.

Is possible to continue with an animation in background when some alert occurs?

I'm looking exactly and only for this solution, e.g. I don't want to call the alert after the animation, but during - and without interruption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`alert()` stops the single thread of JavaScript processing, so no, you can't run animation while an alert box is open.

You would need to use some other kind of alert-like mechanism, for example a modal popup dialog implemented in the DOM without `alert()`. A search for [jquery alert](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+alert) will uncover a number of alert replacements.

Answer (score 2):

The [window.alert()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.alert) method halts the execution of JavaScript in the browser.

As JoDev mentions, you could use jQuery.dialog() as an alternative.

It looks nicer, it's draggable and resizable, and it doesn't halt your script.

It looks something like this:

```
    $('#someDiv').dialog();
```

I happen to have made a fiddle about this the other day:

- http://jsfiddle.net/ZAeLJ/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a box like the [jQuery dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) box to do it...

You can't do it by using `alert()` box, but all of DOM dialog box will allow you to continue the treatment.